# what's the most efficient way to get combination infomation of a model and its "primary key side" of another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am dealing with a  "extending" model of django's User model.Here is my model's definition:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, editable=False)
    real_name = models.CharField('Real Name', max_length=20)
    telephone = models.CharField('Tel', max_length=30)
    company = models.CharField('Company', max_length=30)
    department = models.CharField('Department', max_length=30)
```

as you can see ,my UserProfile model has a "one-to-one"relationship with django's built-in user model by having a "ForeignKey" ,I know another sulotion is using a "OneToOneField",can some one please tell me which one is preffered or more suitable here ?

now ,my situation is ,I am getting the combination information of my UserProfile model and django's built-in User model in a view function.also ,I need to do some pagination here.

```
def get_user_list(request):
    rows_per_page=int(request.POST["rows"])
    page_number=int(request.POST["page"])
    user_list = User.objects.all()# You can see that I only got the built-in User ,
    total=user_list.count()       #but how to get my UserProfile efficiently ?

    paginator = Paginator(user_list, rows_per_page)

    try:
        rows = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:

        rows = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:

        rows = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    result={
        "total":total,
        "rows":rows.object_list,
        }

    jsonSerializer = JSONSerializer()
    return HttpResponse(jsonSerializer.serialize(result),mimetype='application/json')
```

now ,my question is ,how do I get a combination of my UserProile model and the built-in User model to make a queryset ,list,dictionary or whatever ,also I need the combination object to   fit to my existing pagination code .:)  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should read [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in the django documentation as a primer, and then [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) to get an idea on how to query your objects correctly:

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will
>   have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first
>   model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the
>   source model name, lowercased. This Manager returns QuerySets, which
>   can be filtered and manipulated as described in the "Retrieving
>   objects" section above.

So every `user` object has a reverse relationship to all its `profile` objects, in a manager called `userprofile_set`:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user_profile = u.userprofile_set.all()
```

Comment: 'u.userprofile_set.all()' returns a queryset, not a UserProfile instance.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to use a `OneToOneField`, the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE and `user.get_profile()` as documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-user